# Como hago para hacer una accion a una hora en espefica cuando el telefono esta bloquedo?

Tags: android

Tengo este método. El problema es que no me funciona cuando bloqueo el teléfono. Solo me muestra la notificación si el teléfono tiene la pantalla encendida, si lo bloqueo y le pongo que se active solo 5 minutos después (son las 21:00 y lo pongo para las 21:05), no pasa nada. Pero si lo dejo con la pantalla encendida si me muestra la notificación. Gracias de antemano

```
public void activarBroucast(int a,int b) {
      int minutos=a;
      int horas=b;
       Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
       c.add(Calendar.HOUR,horas);
       c.add(Calendar.MINUTE,minutos);
       Timer time = new Timer();
       time.schedule(new TimerTask() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
              lanzarNotificacion();
           }
       },c.getTime());
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Es un error suponer que la aplicación va a mantenerse activa durante X tiempo luego de pasar a segundo plano o si el teléfono es bloqueado. En particular en estos casos la app es pausada e incluso el SO puede decidir destruirla.

### Opción 1

Si es muy importante mostrar la notificación luego de un tiempo exacto, conviene utilizar [Alarmas](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html), ya que ejecutan por fuera del ciclo de vida de la aplicación. Esto es importante porque como decía arriba, el problema que estas teniendo proviene de la app pausándose luego del bloqueo de pantalla.

### Opción 2

En lugar de mostrar la notificación luego de un lapso determinado, lo que puede hacerse es:

- Mostrar la notificación cuando el device es desbloqueado si ya pasaron N milisegundos
- Volver a configurar un task para ejecutar luego de N-DURACION_DE_BLOQUEO milisegundos

Esto produce el mismo efecto que se buscaba.
Una manera de reaccionar al evento de desbloqueo es crear un broadcast que escuche [ACTION_USER_PRESENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT)

### Opción 3

Otra posible solución (aunque no recomendable) es usar un *partial wake lock* para que la app continue su ejecución incluso luego de bloquear la pantalla.

Dependiendo de cuál sea la intención de lo que se está queriendo hacer, recomendaría leer un poco sobre cómo declarar Jobs en android en la [documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html)

Comment: esto es un comentario no una respuesta

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag editado